# need one solution for sql query using pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

```
select PurchaseOrderID
     , [244,231] as FirstEmp
     , [266,274] as secondEmp
     , [231,241] as ThirdEmp 
  from ( select PurchaseOrderID, EmployeeID, TaxAmt
           from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader 
          Where EmployeeID IN (244, 231, 266, 274, 241)
                ) SourceTable
 PIVOT (
   SUM(TaxAmt)
   FOR EmployeeID IN([244,231],[266,274],[231,241])
   ) AS PVT
```

From above query I have to retrieve data for particular GLcode group-wise using pivot.

I have need a result like the following, which means `SUM(TaxAmt)` for one group `GLCode IN (244,231)` and other second For `GLCode IN (266,274)` and third is `GLCode IN (231,241)`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
PurchaseOrderID     [244,231]    [266,274]    [231,241]
---------------------------------------------------------
1                    5678          10456        45643
2                    3456          5643          564
3                    34567         5678          4243
4                    5897          65645         7567
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL is not enough information. I'm guessing Oracle or SQL-Server due to the `pivot`?

Comment: @Ben According to syntax its MSSQL

Comment: @vimal so what is your question ?

Comment: I am use this query  in Microsoft sql server data base... using sql syntax  my intension to group more than one row result in one seprate column and sum their related amount

Comment: @Namir i query this statement in MSSQL

Comment: You have 231 two times is that a typo or is that the way you want it?

Answer (score 5):

```
select PurchaseOrderID,
       sum(case when EmployeeID in (244, 231) then TaxAmt end) as "244,231",
       sum(case when EmployeeID in (266, 274) then TaxAmt end) as "266,274",
       sum(case when EmployeeID in (231, 241) then TaxAmt end) as "231,241"
from PurchaseOrderHeader
where EmployeeID in(244, 231, 266, 274, 241) 
group by PurchaseOrderID
```

Pivot version:

```
select PurchaseOrderID,
       [244]+[231] as "244,231",
       [266]+[274] as "266,274",
       [231]+[241] as "231,241"
from
  (
    select EmployeeID, TaxAmt, PurchaseOrderID
    from PurchaseOrderHeader
    where EmployeeID in(244, 231, 266, 274, 241) 
  ) as P1
pivot
  (
    sum(TaxAmt) for EmployeeID in ([244],[231],[266],[274],[241])
  ) as P2
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this is what you were looking for you should consider ["accepting" this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).